# When I turn on my PC,why it spins for a second then restart automatically? (when I unplug and plug in back the power cable)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, computer-building

I have recently built a custom PC, it works (I think) very well other than the issue below. Since I just built it, I was still playing around with that (changing fan positions, adding new fans, etc.. )

I have noticed that, when I unplugged my power cable and wait at least a minute then try to turn on my PC, it just starts for a second (all the fans, CPU, etc..) then shuts off (everything stops) and after 1-2 seconds it starts automatically and works perfectly fine. (tried this for waiting unplugged for 15 seconds, 30 seconds, that didn't happen)

No crash, no heat issue, everything works perfectly fine.

This **ONLY** happens when I unplug the power cable (for at least a minute) then plug it back. If I don't unplug it and just shut it down from windows and turn on again, it never occurs. (I tried at least 5-10 times)

I should also mentioned that my PC is not over clocked.

I have read on somewhere else that when you unplug the PSU, all the power drains in a minute (based on your PSU) then once you plug in back, it just doesn't have enough power at the beginning!! (As an engineer, this just didn't make sense to me) Even if that is true, is this something to worry about?

Could this be an issue with my PSU ? If it is PSU issue, why that doesn't occur if I don't unplug the power cable?

Eventually, could this cause any damage for my components (mobo, rams, etc.) ?

Here is my system specs:

- Corsair RM850x (850 W) 80 Plus Gold Certified
- ASUS PRO 3.1 X99
- Intel i-7 5820K (3.3ghz)
- EVGA GTX-980ti FTW
- ADATA XPG Z1 DDR4 DRAM MODULE (AX4U2800W8G17-DRZ) 2800MHZ 2x8GB Kit
- Corsair Obsedian 750D - (with 3 x 140mm stock fans)
- Aftermarket fans - (3 x 140mm fans)
- CoolerMaster V8-GTS CPU Fan

**EDIT:** I thought maybe I have overloaded the PSU with fans (which  I believe 850W should handle it very well) but this happens even when I unplugged the after market 3 x 140mm fans as well